# Problem showing data from incoming webhook | Taiga --> Rocketchat

Tags: notifications, webhooks, rocket.chat, taiga

I'm trying to generate alerts based on notifications from Taiga project management software (when a user creates a project for example). These alerts will arrive to a specific Rocket.chat channel.

For this I am using the incoming Rocketchat webhooks: https://docs.rocket.chat/administrator-guides/integrations/

So I created the incoming webhook and entered the data into Taiga:

[Configuring the webhook in Taiga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yezk.png)

Once all this is done I check that the message arrives at the destination correctly:

[Example of a notification message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onJhO.png)

Indeed, the message is received but it doesn't show any information. When a user history, an issue or any modification that leads to an alert is created, it is received in rocketchat but it doesn't show any information (empty message).

[Payload sended by Taiga to Rocketchat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tyVx.png)

Does anyone know why he won't show me any information?

Thank you very much in advance

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to post notifications to a Rocket Chat channel, when a taiga user created a project in taiga? I would not know, how you can do that. But, as far as I can see, your screenshot shows the configuration of a generic webhook in a project after that project has been created. Therefore, I hope it is sufficient to post notifications from that project to your Rocket Chat channel. Here is my answer for this case:

I observed a similar behavior. Using the generic webhook, I could only trigger empty posts in my Rocket Chat channel by clicking on "test" for that webhook.

However, the Rocket Chat API seems to be compatible with the Slack API, cf. https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/1728#issuecomment-166669379.

In contrast to the generic webhook, the Slack plugin for taiga (https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-contrib-slack) worked out of the box (https://tree.taiga.io/support/contrib-plugins/slack-integration/).

Only my browser gave me some hassle, because it cached the taiga webpage and after installing the Slack plugin a simple page reload was not enough to display the "Plugins" entry in the "Admin" menu of the project. "Shift+reload" did the job. But apart from that standard issue, everything worked.

Comment: Rocketchat + Taiga integration is possible using the Slack Plugin. Thanks you very much! https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-contrib-slack